# How to overcome component shrinking in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to display some query results on a GridLayout but the results keep on shrinking once it is more than one. On codename one GUI Builder, I placed a container with GridLayout, 1 row and 4 columns within another container with BoxLayout Y. How can I overcome this please?

Please check the attached picture for more clarification.

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9WS1.jpg)

Best Regards,
Yahya-Imam Munir Kolapo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the row count to match the number of actual rows you are adding which you can calculate based on the number of components / the number of rows.

You need to do this by code since the GUI builder can't know that at this stage.